# How can I set model input for an object attribute that exist in layers of list with asp tag-helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a model that consists of many layers. On the main frame, there will be an object for basic input and a list of object that contains a model to store view data but inside it, each item will have a data field to store its new value which I will also consider as input data. My problem is I don't know how to call, set that data field inside tag helper since it's cover by list of list. What I want to achieve is to pass all data back to controller.

```
public class TenDongThuocCongTy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CauHinhBangId { get; set; }
    public string CongThucDong { get; set; }
    public string TenDong { get; set; }
    public int CauHinhBang_Cha { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string inputValue { get; set; }
}
public class LayThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhVien
{
    public int Cttv_ThuocBangId { get; set; }
    public int CauHinhBangID { get; set; }
    public int CttvId { get; set; }
    public string TenDong { get; set; }
    public string CongThucDong { get; set; }
    public string DichCongThuc { get; set; }
    public List<TenDongThuocCongTy> TenDongThuocCongTies { get; set; }
}
public class MuaVuTruocUpsertModel
{
    
    [DisplayName("Day")]
    public DateTime? Ngay { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Number")]
    [DisplayName("Number")]
    public int? STT { get; set; }
}

public class TongHopItemMuaVuTruoc
{
    public List<LayThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhVien> MenuItemMuaVutruoc { get; set; }
    public MuaVuTruocUpsertModel muaVuTruocModel {get; set;}
}
```

As in the model above, I want to access to the defined meaning of 'inputValue' then put it in:

```
@model MFF.Infrastructure.Models.TongHopItemMuaVuTruoc
<input asp-for="inputModel" type="text"/>
```

Comment: What the associated PageModel class(Index.cshtml.cs, I assume the main page is Index.cshtml.) looks like, can you post the related code? Besides, here are some relates article about model binding in Razor page, you could refer to them: [Model Binding](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding) and [Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form).

Comment: May I ask what does the name of the cshtml have any affect on the model? Also I will update my cshtml for better understanding.

Comment: The issue is not related the name of the cshtml, I just want to see the page model in the Main page, like [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Msk.png). From your editing, I know that you will return the TongHopItemMuaVuTruoc model to the view page, and it seems that your application is an Asp.net Core MVC application, right? I will focus on it and will give an answer later.

Comment: "What I want is to pass data from cshtml to Controller, not the other way around." Please add it in your question. From your previous description, it seems that you want to render the value, instead of pass the data from cshtml to the controller.

Comment: What can 'asp-for' does something else? Isn't the point of it is to pass data from Page to Controller?

Comment: The `asp-for` attribute extracts the name of the specified model property into the rendered HTML. Refer [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to achieve is to pass all data back to controller.

To pass data from view to the controller, you could use the following methods:

1. Use [asp.net core Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and Submit button to submit the form.
2. Use JQuery Ajax submits the form data or a JavaScript object to the controller.

Please refer the following sample code:

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index2()
    {
        TongHopItemMuaVuTruoc tongHopItemMuaVuTruoc = new TongHopItemMuaVuTruoc()
        {
            MenuItemMuaVutruoc = new List<LayThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhVien>()
             {
                 new LayThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhVien()
                 {
                      TenDongThuocCongTies = new List<TenDongThuocCongTy>()
                      {
                           new TenDongThuocCongTy()
                           {
                                TenDong = "TD 1",
                                inputValue = "AA",
                           },
                           new TenDongThuocCongTy()
                           {
                                TenDong = "TD 2",
                                inputValue = "BB",
                           }
                      }
                 }
             }
        };

        return View(tongHopItemMuaVuTruoc);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index2(TongHopItemMuaVuTruoc tongHopItemMuaVuTruoc)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do something
        }
        return View(tongHopItemMuaVuTruoc);
    }
```

Index2 View page (Index2.cshtml): Here I add two buttons, the "Submit" button will submit the form using the first method, the "Ajax Submit" button will submit the form using JQuery Ajax method. And you can add other properties using the similar tag.

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.TongHopItemMuaVuTruoc

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="mainform" asp-action="Index2">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="muaVuTruocModel.Ngay" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="muaVuTruocModel.Ngay" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="muaVuTruocModel.Ngay" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="muaVuTruocModel.STT" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="muaVuTruocModel.STT" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="muaVuTruocModel.STT" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.MenuItemMuaVutruoc.Count(); i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < Model.MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].TenDongThuocCongTies.Count; j++)
                {
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <input asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[j].TenDong" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <input asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[j].inputValue" type="text" />
                    </div>
                }
            }

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" /> <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Ajax Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the end of the above view page, add the following scripts:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Test/Index2",
                method: "Post",
                data: $("#mainform").serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    alert("sueess");
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
}
```

The output like this:

[image]
Reference:

[Razor syntax reference for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: What I want is to pass data from cshtml to Controller, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out. What I have to do is treated my model as an array object. The code below returns all of my data, including default data and newly input ones, back to Controller successfully.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.MenuItemMuaVutruoc.Count; i++)
{
//Value for Model
<input type="hidden" asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].CttvId" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].Cttv_ThuocBangId" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].CauHinhBangID" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].TenDong" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].CongThucDong" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].DichCongThuc" />
@for (int j = 0; j < danhmuc.TenDongThuocCongTies.Count; j++)
{
//Value cho tung item
<input type="hidden" asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[j].Id" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[j].CauHinhBangId" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[j].CongThucDong" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[j].CauHinhBang_Cha" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[j].TenDong" />
var item = danhmuc.TenDongThuocCongTies.ElementAt(j);
<h6 class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4  mt-lg-2 mt-md-2 mt-2 mt-sm-2">
   @item.TenDong
</h6>
<input asp-for="MenuItemMuaVutruoc[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[j].inputValue" type="text" class="form-control col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 mt-lg-2 mt-md-2 mt-2 mt-sm-2" />
}
}
```